# Count keywords and word stems in tweets

Tags: r, text, twitter, count, keyword

I have a large dataframe consisting of tweets, and keyword dictionaries loaded as values that have words associated with morality (`kw_Moral`) and emotion (`kw_Emo`). In the past I have used the keyword dictionaries to subset a dataframe to get only the tweets that have one or more of the keywords present.

For example, to create a subset with only those tweets that have emotional keywords, I loaded in my keyword dictionary...

```
kw_Emo <- c("abusi*", "accept", "accepta*", "accepted", 
        "accepting", "accepts", "ache*", "aching", "active*", "admir*", 
        "ador*", "advantag*", "adventur*", "advers*", "affection*", "afraid", 
        "aggravat*", "aggress*", "agoniz*", "agony", "agree", "agreeab*", 
        "agreed", "agreeing", "agreement*", "agrees", "alarm*", "alone", 
        "alright*", "amaz*", "amor*", "amus*", "anger*", "angr*", "anguish*", 
        "annoy*", "antagoni*", "anxi*", "aok", "apath*", "appall*", "appreciat*", 
        "apprehens*", "argh*", "argu*", "arrogan*", "asham*", "assault*", 
        "asshole*", "assur*", "attachment*", "attract*", "aversi*", "avoid*", 
        "award*", "awesome", "awful", "awkward*", "bashful*", "bastard*", 
        "battl*", "beaten", "beaut*", "beloved", "benefic*", "benevolen*", 
        "benign*", "best", "better", "bitch*", "bitter*", "blam*", "bless*", 
        "bold*", "bonus*", "bore*", "boring", "bother*", "brave*", "bright*", 
        "brillian*", "broke", "burden*", "calm*", "cared", "carefree", 
        "careful*", "careless*", "cares", "casual", "casually", "certain*", 
        "challeng*", "champ*", "charit*", "charm*", "cheer*", "cherish*", 
        "chuckl*", "clever*", "comed*", "comfort*", "commitment*", "complain*", 
        "compliment*", "concerned", "confidence", "confident", "confidently", 
        "confront*", "confus*", "considerate", "contempt*", "contented*", 
        "contentment", "contradic*", "convinc*", "cool", "courag*", "crap", 
        "crappy", "craz*", "create*", "creati*", "credit*", "cried", 
        "cries", "critical", "critici*", "crude*", "cry", "crying", "cunt*", 
        "cut", "cute*", "cutie*", "cynic", "danger*", "daring", "darlin*", 
        "daze*", "dear*", "decay*", "defeat*", "defect*", "definite", 
        "definitely", "degrad*", "delectabl*", "delicate*", "delicious*", 
        "deligh*", "depress*", "depriv*", "despair*", "desperat*", "despis*", 
        "destruct*", "determina*", "determined", "devastat*", "difficult*", 
        "digni*", "disadvantage*", "disagree*", "disappoint*", "disaster*", 
        "discomfort*", "discourag*", "dishearten*", "disillusion*", "dislike", 
        "disliked", "dislikes", "disliking", "dismay*", "dissatisf*", 
        "distract*", "distraught", "distress*", "distrust*", "disturb*", 
        "divin*", "domina*", "doom*", "dork*", "doubt*", "dread*", "dull*", 
        "dumb*", "dump*", "dwell*", "dynam*", "eager*", "ease*", "easie*", 
        "easily", "easiness", "easing", "easy*", "ecsta*", "efficien*", 
        "egotis*", "elegan*", "embarrass*", "emotion", "emotional", "empt*", 
        "encourag*", "energ*", "engag*", "enjoy*", "enrag*", "entertain*", 
        "enthus*", "envie*", "envious", "excel*", "excit*", "excruciat*", 
        "exhaust*", "fab", "fabulous*", "fail*", "fake", "fantastic*", 
        "fatal*", "fatigu*", "favor*", "favour*", "fear", "feared", "fearful*", 
        "fearing", "fearless*", "fears", "feroc*", "festiv*", "feud*", 
        "fiery", "fiesta*", "fine", "fired", "flatter*", "flawless*", 
        "flexib*", "flirt*", "flunk*", "foe*", "fond", "fondly", "fondness", 
        "fool*", "forgave", "forgiv*", "fought", "frantic*", "freak*", 
        "free", "freeb*", "freed*", "freeing", "freely", "freeness", 
        "freer", "frees*", "friend*", "fright*", "frustrat*", "fuck", 
        "fucked*", "fucker*", "fuckin*", "fucks", "fume*", "fuming", 
        "fun", "funn*", "furious*", "fury", "geek*", "genero*", "gentle", 
        "gentler", "gentlest", "gently", "giggl*", "giver*", "giving", 
        "glad", "gladly", "glamor*", "glamour*", "gloom*", "glori*", 
        "glory", "goddam*", "gorgeous*", "gossip*", "grace", "graced", 
        "graceful*", "graces", "graci*", "grand", "grande*", "gratef*", 
        "grati*", "grave*", "great", "grief", "griev*", "grim*", "grin", 
        "grinn*", "grins", "grouch*", "grr*", "guilt*", "ha", "haha*", 
        "handsom*", "happi*", "happy", "harass*", "hated", "hateful*", 
        "hater*", "hates", "hating", "hatred", "hazy", "heartbreak*", 
        "heartbroke*", "heartfelt", "heartless*", "heartwarm*", "heh*", 
        "hellish", "helper*", "helpful*", "helping", "helpless*", "helps", 
        "hesita*", "hilarious", "hoho*", "homesick*", "honour*", "hope", 
        "hoped", "hopeful", "hopefully", "hopefulness", "hopeless*", 
        "hopes", "hoping", "horr*", "hostil*", "hug", "hugg*", "hugs", 
        "humiliat*", "humor*", "humour*", "hurra*", "idiot", "ignor*", 
        "impatien*", "impersonal", "impolite*", "importan*", "impress*", 
        "improve*", "improving", "inadequa*", "incentive*", "indecis*", 
        "ineffect*", "inferior*", "inhib*", "innocen*", "insecur*", "insincer*", 
        "inspir*", "insult*", "intell*", "interest*", "interrup*", "intimidat*", 
        "invigor*", "irrational*", "irrita*", "isolat*", "jaded", "jealous*", 
        "jerk", "jerked", "jerks", "joke*", "joking", "joll*", "joy*", 
        "keen*", "kidding", "kind", "kindly", "kindn*", "kiss*", "laidback", 
        "lame*", "laugh*", "lazie*", "lazy", "liabilit*", "libert*", 
        "lied", "lies", "like", "likeab*", "liked", "likes", "liking", 
        "livel*", "LMAO", "LOL", "lone*", "longing*", "lose", "loser*", 
        "loses", "losing", "loss*", "lost", "lous*", "love", "loved", 
        "lovely", "lover*", "loves", "loving*", "low*", "luck", "lucked", 
        "lucki*", "luckless*", "lucks", "lucky", "ludicrous*", "lying", 
        "mad", "maddening", "madder", "maddest", "madly", "magnific*", 
        "maniac*", "masochis*", "melanchol*", "merit*", "merr*", "mess", 
        "messy", "miser*", "miss", "missed", "misses", "missing", "mistak*", 
        "mock", "mocked", "mocker*", "mocking", "mocks", "molest*", "mooch*", 
        "mood", "moodi*", "moods", "moody", "moron*", "mourn*", "nag*", 
        "nast*", "neat*", "needy", "neglect*", "nerd*", "nervous*", "neurotic*", 
        "nice*", "numb*", "nurtur*", "obnoxious*", "obsess*", "offence*", 
        "offens*", "ok", "okay", "okays", "oks", "openminded*", "openness", 
        "opportun*", "optimal*", "optimi*", "original", "outgoing", "outrag*", 
        "overwhelm*", "pained", "painf*", "paining", "painl*", "pains", 
        "palatabl*", "panic*", "paradise", "paranoi*", "partie*", "party*", 
        "passion*", "pathetic*", "peculiar*", "perfect*", "personal", 
        "perver*", "pessimis*", "petrif*", "pettie*", "petty*", "phobi*", 
        "piss*", "piti*", "pity*", "play", "played", "playful*", "playing", 
        "plays", "pleasant*", "please*", "pleasing", "pleasur*", "poison*", 
        "popular*", "positiv*", "prais*", "precious*", "pressur*", "prettie*", 
        "pretty", "prick*", "pride", "privileg*", "prize*", "problem*", 
        "profit*", "promis*", "protested", "protesting", "proud*", "puk*", 
        "radian*", "rage*", "raging", "rancid*", "rape*", "raping", "rapist*", 
        "readiness", "ready", "reassur*", "reek*", "regret*", "reject*", 
        "relax*", "relief", "reliev*", "reluctan*", "remorse*", "repress*", 
        "resent*", "resign*", "resolv*", "restless*", "revigor*", "reward*", 
        "rich*", "ridicul*", "rigid*", "risk*", "ROFL", "romanc*", "romantic*", 
        "rotten", "rude*", "sad", "sadde*", "sadly", "sadness", "sarcas*", 
        "satisf*", "savage*", "scare*", "scaring", "scary", "sceptic*", 
        "scream*", "screw*", "selfish*", "sentimental*", "serious", "seriously", 
        "seriousness", "severe*", "shake*", "shaki*", "shaky", "share", 
        "shared", "shares", "sharing", "shit*", "shock*", "shook", "shy*", 
        "sigh", "sighed", "sighing", "sighs", "silli*", "silly", "sincer*", 
        "skeptic*", "smart*", "smil*", "smother*", "smug*", "snob*", 
        "sob", "sobbed", "sobbing", "sobs", "sociab*", "solemn*", "sorrow*", 
        "sorry", "soulmate*", "special", "splend*", "stammer*", "stank", 
        "startl*", "stink*", "strain*", "strange", "strength*", "stress*", 
        "strong*", "struggl*", "stubborn*", "stunk", "stunned", "stuns", 
        "stupid*", "stutter*", "succeed*", "success*", "suck", "sucked", 
        "sucker*", "sucks", "sucky", "sunnier", "sunniest", "sunny", 
        "sunshin*", "super", "superior*", "support", "supported", "supporter*", 
        "supporting", "supportive*", "supports", "suprem*", "sure*", 
        "surpris*", "suspicio*", "sweet", "sweetheart*", "sweetie*", 
        "sweetly", "sweetness*", "sweets", "talent*", "tantrum*", "tears", 
        "teas*", "tehe", "temper", "tempers", "tender*", "tense*", "tensing", 
        "tension*", "terribl*", "terrific*", "terrified", "terrifies", 
        "terrify", "terrifying", "terror*", "thank", "thanked", "thankf*", 
        "thanks", "thief", "thieve*", "thoughtful*", "threat*", "thrill*", 
        "ticked", "timid*", "toleran*", "tortur*", "tough*", "traged*", 
        "tragic*", "tranquil*", "trauma*", "treasur*", "treat", "trembl*", 
        "trick*", "trite", "triumph*", "trivi*", "troubl*", "TRUE", "trueness", 
        "truer", "truest", "truly", "trust*", "truth*", "turmoil", "ugh", 
        "ugl*", "unattractive", "uncertain*", "uncomfortabl*", "uncontrol*", 
        "uneas*", "unfortunate*", "unfriendly", "ungrateful*", "unhapp*", 
        "unimportant", "unimpress*", "unkind", "unlov*", "unpleasant", 
        "unprotected", "unsavo*", "unsuccessful*", "unsure*", "unwelcom*", 
        "upset*", "uptight*", "useful*", "useless*", "vain", "valuabl*", 
        "valuing", "vanity", "vicious*", "vigor*", "vigour*", "villain*", 
        "violat*", "virtuo*", "vital*", "vulnerab*", "vulture*", "warfare*", 
        "warm*", "warred", "weak*", "wealth*", "weapon*", "weep*", "weird*", 
        "welcom*", "well*", "wept", "whine*", "whining", "willing", "wimp*", 
        "win", "winn*", "wins", "wisdom", "wise*", "witch", "woe*", "won", 
        "wonderf*", "worr*", "worse*", "worship*", "worst", "wow*", "yay", 
        "yays","yearn*","stench*") %>% paste0(collapse="|")and then filtered my dataframe with the keywords...
```

`tweets_E <- tweets[with(tweets, grepl(paste0("\\b(?:",paste(kw_Emo, collapse="|"),")\\b"), text)),]`

**How do I expand on this process to count exactly how many of the dictionary words appear in each tweet?** In other words, I want to add a vector to the dataframe, say `EmoWordCount`, that will show the number of emotional words appear in each tweet.

---

Here's a reproducible sample of my data:

`dput(droplevels(head(TestTweets, 20)))`

```
structure(list(Time = c("24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:03", "24/06/2016 10:55:03"
), clean_text = c("mayagoodfellow as always making sense of it all for us ive never felt less welcome in this country brexit  httpstcoiai5xa9ywv", 
"never underestimate power of stupid people in a democracy brexit", 
"a quick guide to brexit and beyond after britain votes to quit eu httpstcos1xkzrumvg httpstcocniutojkt0", 
"this selfinflicted wound will be his legacy cameron falls on sword after brexit euref httpstcoegph3qonbj httpstcohbyhxodeda", 
"so the uk is out cameron resigned scotland wants to leave great britain sinn fein plans to unify ireland and its o", 
"this is a very good summary no biasspinagenda of the legal ramifications of the leave result brexit httpstcolobtyo48ng", 
"you cant make this up cornwall votes out immediately pleads to keep eu cash this was never a rehearsal httpstco", 
"no matter the outcome brexit polls demonstrate how quickly half of any population can be convinced to vote against itself q", 
"i wouldnt mind so much but the result is based on a pack of lies and unaccountable promises democracy didnt win brexit pro", 
"so the uk is out cameron resigned scotland wants to leave great britain sinn fein plans to unify ireland and its o", 
"absolutely brilliant poll on brexit by yougov httpstcoepevg1moaw", 
"retweeted mikhail golub golub\r\n\r\nbrexit to be followed by grexit departugal italeave fruckoff czechout httpstcoavkpfesddz", 
"think the brexit campaign relies on the same sort of logic that drpepper does whats the worst that can happen thingsthatarewellbrexit", 
"am baffled by nigel farages claim that brexit is a victory for real people as if the 47 voting remain are fucking smu", 
"not one of the uks problems has been solved by brexit vote migration inequality the uks centurylong decline as", 
"scotland should never leave eu  calls for new independence vote grow httpstcorudiyvthia brexit", 
"the most articulate take on brexit is actually this ft reader comment today httpstco98b4dwsrtv", 
"65 million refugees half of them are children  maybe instead of fighting each other we should be working hand in hand ", 
"im laughing at people who voted for brexit but are complaining about the exchange rate affecting their holiday\r\nremain", 
"life is too short to wear boring shoes  brexit")), .Names = c("Time", 
"clean_text"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

---

Here is the code I used from Francisco:

```
library(stringr)

 for (x in 1:length(kw_Emo)) {
   if (grepl("[*]", kw_Emo[x]) == TRUE) {
     kw_Emo[x] <- substr(kw_Emo[x],1,nchar(kw_Emo[x])-1)
   }
 }

 for (x in 1:length(kw_Emo)) {
   TestTweets[, kw_Emo[x]] <- 0
 }

 for (x in 1:nrow(TestTweets)) {
   partials <- data.frame(str_split(TestTweets[x,2], " "), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
   partials <- partials[partials[] != ""]
   for(y in 1:length(partials)) {
     for (z in 1:length(kw_Emo)) {
       if (kw_Emo[z] == partials[y]) {
         TestTweets[x, kw_Emo[z]] <- TestTweets[x, kw_Emo[z]] + 1
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Here is the output from Francisco's solution below (I renamed the new column `EmoWordCount`):

```
structure(list(Time = c("24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:04", 
"24/06/2016 10:55:04", "24/06/2016 10:55:03", "24/06/2016 10:55:03"
), clean_text = c("mayagoodfellow as always making sense of it all for us ive never felt less welcome in this country brexit  httpstcoiai5xa9ywv", 
"never underestimate power of stupid people in a democracy brexit", 
"a quick guide to brexit and beyond after britain votes to quit eu httpstcos1xkzrumvg httpstcocniutojkt0", 
"this selfinflicted wound will be his legacy cameron falls on sword after brexit euref httpstcoegph3qonbj httpstcohbyhxodeda", 
"so the uk is out cameron resigned scotland wants to leave great britain sinn fein plans to unify ireland and its o", 
"this is a very good summary no biasspinagenda of the legal ramifications of the leave result brexit httpstcolobtyo48ng", 
"you cant make this up cornwall votes out immediately pleads to keep eu cash this was never a rehearsal httpstco", 
"no matter the outcome brexit polls demonstrate how quickly half of any population can be convinced to vote against itself q", 
"i wouldnt mind so much but the result is based on a pack of lies and unaccountable promises democracy didnt win brexit pro", 
"so the uk is out cameron resigned scotland wants to leave great britain sinn fein plans to unify ireland and its o", 
"absolutely brilliant poll on brexit by yougov httpstcoepevg1moaw", 
"retweeted mikhail golub golub\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nbrexit to be followed by grexit departugal italeave fruckoff czechout httpstcoavkpfesddz", 
"think the brexit campaign relies on the same sort of logic that drpepper does whats the worst that can happen thingsthatarewellbrexit", 
"am baffled by nigel farages claim that brexit is a victory for real people as if the 47 voting remain are fucking smu", 
"not one of the uks problems has been solved by brexit vote migration inequality the uks centurylong decline as", 
"scotland should never leave eu  calls for new independence vote grow httpstcorudiyvthia brexit", 
"the most articulate take on brexit is actually this ft reader comment today httpstco98b4dwsrtv", 
"65 million refugees half of them are children  maybe instead of fighting each other we should be working hand in hand ", 
"im laughing at people who voted for brexit but are complaining about the exchange rate affecting their holiday\r\n\r\nremain", 
"life is too short to wear boring shoes  brexit"), EmoWordCount = c(3, 
2, 0, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 2, 5, 11, 6, 6, 5, 1, 7, 6, 4)), .Names = c("Time", 
"clean_text", "EmoWordCount"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I actually could not find any of `kw_Emo` in atleast first 5 of `TestTweets$clean_text`. Is this intentional or I am missing something?

Comment: Ah, sorry. The dictionary I've posted is only a small sample of a much larger dictionary. I will add in the full length dictionary to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know if this is the optimal solution, but it works just fine. You should use the "stringr" package.

```
library(stringr)

 for (x in 1:length(keywords)) {
  if (grepl("[*]", keywords[x]) == TRUE) {
    keywords[x] <- substr(keywords[x],1,nchar(keywords[x])-1)
      }
    }
```

Here I remove the "*" symbol from some of your keywords (which I understand you want to analyze their partial inclusion in a string.

> IMPORTANT:

should use the regex expression [*] to catch the * symbol.

```
for (x in 1:length(keywords)) {
  dataframe[, keywords[x]] <- 0
    }
```

Just creating the new columns with default values in 0.

```
for (x in 1:nrow(dataframe)) {
  partials <- data.frame(str_split(dataframe[x,2], " "), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  partials <- partials[partials[] != ""]
  for(y in 1:length(partials)) {
    for (z in 1:length(keywords)) {
      if (keywords[z] == partials[y]) {
        dataframe[x, keywords[z]] <- dataframe[x, keywords[z]] + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You split each Tweet to a vector of words, see if the keyword is equal to any, add +1 if they are present and end up with the same dataframe but with new columns for each keyword.

I tested it with your keywords, and gives the correct answer.

Comment: This successfully added a numeric column to my dataframe where it looks like the keywords would be counted for each tweet, but unfortunately it's showing all 0s, which I know is not actually the case. As with @TimBiegeleisen's solution below, might this be affect by the use of word stems in the keywords (e.g. "abusi*", "ador*")? Can you think of someway around this?

Comment: I thought this worked, but with a closer look, there must be something wrong. The counts are not accurate. For instance, in observation 14, it reported 11 emotional words when that is clearly not true. Any idea what's going on? I added a sample of my data that was output after adapting your code.

Comment: Checking it now

Comment: Good catches! I'll go through and revise the dictionary. Thanks very much for this.

Comment: Just updated the answer with the solution for the A issue. Should have used regex [*] to find the * symbol. I you clean your keywords it should work fine.

Comment: I updated the answer. When checking for thwe keywords I went back to the exact word match option. Otherwise you could fin errors like keyword "rage" detected in the word "farages".

Comment: Hey Francisco, I just got back to this and unfortunately I am still having the same problem. I put up the code I used in the main post if you can take a look.

Comment: Hi @Jason B I found the problem. At the end of your keywords list you are pasting al them together and joining them with a "|". `%>% paste0(collapse="|")`. Remove that part and keep them as a list and it will run smoothly.

Comment: Hi @Francisco, thanks again for this answer. I am now trying to use this code on a similar project, but really need to account for the word stems, not just the exact word matches. Do you know how to adapt your solution so that words in the dictionary with [*] get treated as stems? Ex. so that `ador*` picks up `adore`, `adorable`, and `adoringly` ???

Comment: Hi @Jason. Yes it’s possible. I’ll try to get into it ASAP.

Comment: Hi @Francisco. Any luck? I'm wondering if we could first use a stringr pattern to replace occurrences of a word stem with the exact characters, and then use your exact match loops. Something like `stringr::str_replace_all(x, "ador[a-z]+", "ador")`. But I'm unsure how to do this with my large dictionary and numerous word stems. Maybe you have an idea of how to alter your loop where you remove `[*]`, which essentially identifies all word stems?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement would seem to lend itself to a matrix type output, where, for example, the tweets are rows, and each term is a column, with the cell value being the number of occurrences.  Here is a base R solution using `gsub`:

```
terms <- c("cat", "hat", "bat")
tweets <- c("The cat in a hat met the man with the hat and a bat",
            "That cat was a fast cat!",
            "I bought a baseball bat while wearing a hat")

output <- sapply(terms, function(x) {
    sapply(tweets, function(y) {
        (nchar(y) - nchar(gsub(paste0("\\b", x, "\\b"), "", y))) / nchar(x)
    })
})

                                                    cat hat bat
The cat in a hat met the man with the hat and a bat   1   2   1
That cat was a fast cat!                              2   0   0
I bought a baseball bat while wearing a hat           0   1   1
```

This approaches first iterates each keyword in `terms` using `sapply`, and then iterates each tweet.  For each keyword/tweet combination, it computes the number of occurrences.  The trick I used was to compare the length of the original tweet against the length of the same tweet with all occurrences of a keyword removed, that difference then normalized by the length of the particular keyword.

**Edit:**

If you instead want a total sum of keyword occurrences for each tweet, then we can just call `rowSums` on the above matrix:

```
rowSums(output)

The cat in a hat met the man with the hat and a bat
                                                  4
                           That cat was a fast cat!
                                                  2
        I bought a baseball bat while wearing a hat
                                                  2
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful for the future. But since my dictionary has a large number of terms, have a count for each word would end up being inefficient for my intended analyses. Is there a way to adapt your code to simply generate a single keyword count? (Sorry for the confusion--I had only posted a tiny section of my actual dictionary. The full dictionary is posted now.)

Comment: @JasonB I updated to cover your use case.  Not sure if this is the most efficient solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: I tried out your solution on my sample from the original post: `TestTweets <- sapply(kw_Emo, function(x) {
  sapply(TestTweets, function(y) {
    (nchar(y) - nchar(gsub(paste0("\\b", x, "\\b"), "", y))) / nchar(x)
  })
})` But it outputs a single vector of 0s for some reason. Maybe you could give it a try on the reproducible data I posted? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: My solution won't work exactly correctly with your data, because your keywords aren't really keywords at all.  Most of them end with wildcards, meaning there is no way to know how long each actual match is.  I recommending using a list of actual keywords.

Comment: Ah, yeah I'm using them as word stems. I got the dictionary from an previously approved source so unfortunately I have to stick with the dictionary as is.